# Restart a daemon without root in OSX

Tags: macos, sudo, launchd, daemon, launchctl

On OSX 10.10 I created a `plist` file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` to start at launch an *OpenVPN* connection. However I encountered DNS problems when going from an internet interface to another (as WiFi to LAN Network) and thought that I needed to restart my *OpenVPN* daemon with `launchctl` to fix it.
But with this method I need to go to a console, type a monstrous `launchctl`'s command with `sudo` and, of course, type my admin password.

I can't find this method optimized, so I would love to know **another way to restart my daemon without typing anything or less** !

Thanks

Comment: I've found debugging an Agent in `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents` is easier for the reasons you stated.  After you're finished, don't forget to change permissions and launch with `sudo` when moving it back to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird Thanks for the tip, however I don't really know what I would debug as I only need to restart my daemon or find a better way to handle interface change with OpenVPN !